# Is there any mention of a fountain of youth in the Purans?

Tags: puranas

The concept of [the fountain of youth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_of_Youth) is common in many other religions. Are there any similar mentions in Hindu purans? (I searched quite a lot, but I did not find any. Perhaps it is known by a different name?)

Immortality and Eternal Youth go hand in hand. The concept of Amrutha is present, which when we consume, gives us immortality. Is there a similar portion to gain youthfulness?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Are there any similar mentions in Hindu puranas. ?

Yes there is similar concept  to fountain of youth or pond of youth in Hinduism Puranas. Which is called Siddha -Kunada OR Ashvini Kunda. Created  by the siddha Rishis.

Which is mentioned in Story of Rishi Chavana regaing his youth back .The story Rishi Chavana Bathing in certain pond called Siddha-kunda with ashvini kumaras and regaining his youth and beauty is mentioned in Skanda 9 - Chapter - 3  of [**Shrremad Bhagvat Purana**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3)  - SB 9.3: The Marriage of Sukanyā and Cyavana Muni.

**Background** - When the heavenly physicians the Aśvinī-kumāra brothers once visited Cyavana Muni, the muni requested them to give him back his youth. These two physicians took Cyavana Muni to a particular lake, in which they bathed and regained full youth. After this, Sukanyā could not distinguish her husband. She then surrendered unto the Aśvinī-kumāras, who were very satisfied with her chastity and who therefore introduced her again to her husband. Cyavana Muni.

---

> कस्यचित् त्वथ कालस्य नासत्यावाश्रमागतौ ।
>  तौ पूजयित्वा प्रोवाच वयो
>   मे दत्तमीश्वरौ ॥11॥
>
> kasyacit tv atha kālasya nāsatyāv āśramāgatau
>  tau pūjayitvā
>   provāca vayo me dattam īśvarau
>    Thereafter, some time having
>   passed, the Asvini-kumara brothers, the heavenly physicians, happened
>   to come to Cyavana Muni’s asrama. After offering them respectful
>   obeisances, Cyavana Muni requested them to give him youthful life, for
>   they were able to do so. [**SB 9.3.11**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/11)
>
> ---
>
> ग्रहं ग्रहीष्ये
>   सोमस्य यज्ञे वामप्यसोमपोः ।
>  क्रियतां मे वयोरूपं प्रमदानां
>   यदीप्सितम् ॥12॥
>
> grahaḿ grahīṣye somasya yajñe vām apy asoma-poḥ
>  kriyatāḿ me
>   vayo-rūpaḿ pramadānāḿ yad īpsitam
>
> Cyavana Muni said: Although you are ineligible to drink soma-rasa in
>   sacrifices, I promise to give you a full pot of it. **Kindly arrange
>   beauty and youth for me,** [**SB 9.3.12**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/12)
>
> ---
>
> बाढमित्यूचतुर्विप्रमभिनन्द्य भिषक्तमौ ।
>  निमज्जतां भवानस्मिन् ह्रदे
>   सिद्धविनिर्मिते ॥13 ॥
>
> bāḍham ity ūcatur vipram abhinandya bhiṣaktamau nimajjatāḿ bhavān
>   asmin hrade siddha-vinirmite
>
> The great physicians, the Asvini-kumaras, very gladly accepted Cyavana
>   Muni’s proposal. Thus they told the brahmana, “Just dive into this
>   lake of successful life.” [**SB 9.3.13**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/13)

After taking dip in the kunda Rishi Chavana , who was very old and unattractive became youthful again.

---

This kunda is also mentioned in [**Vamana purana**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vamana-purana/chapter-34/topic-1)  - Chapter 34 - Verse 31-  Account of the forests , rivers and Tirthas of Kurukshetra. (see page no. 142)    ,Which the Vamana Purana is calling Ashivini Kunda OR Ashivini  Tirtha , and is near to Kurukshetra.

> अश्विनोस्तिर्थमासाद्य श्रद्धावान्यो जितेन्द्रिय : |
>  रूपस्य भागी भवति
>   यशस्वी च भवेन्नर : || VP 34.31||
>
> The man who exercise checks on his senses and has keen obeisance ,
>   **gets a beautiful complexion and frame as blessings for bathing in the
>   holy place of Ashvini-Kumaras.**

---

So the similar concept like fountain of youth is also present in puranas with slight difference that its name a kunda rather than fountain which can restores youth .
[image]